# Getting Error for Code set 1 but not for Code Set 2

Tags: sql, oracle

--Code Set 1 below fails when Code Set 2 runs fine.  The only difference between the two sets of SQL Syntax is that an additional condition of a.struct_doc_id=13685 is placed within the Subquery to create "GetAllSubTypes".  The additional condition is the limiter of "and a.struct_doc_id=13685".  The error that I get in Code Set 1 is "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row 01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row.  Can someone please help?

```
-- Both Code Sets 1 and Code Set 2 are below each other

-- CODE SET 1

with max_amend
as
(
select STRUCT_DOC_id, max(amendment_number) max_amend from MN_STRUCTURED_CONTRACT 
group by STRUCT_DOC_id
),

Extensions
as
(
select struct_doc_id, count(*) - 1 Num_Extensions
from 
(
    select distinct struct_doc_id, end_date from MN_STRUCTURED_doc_ver
)
group by struct_doc_id
),

Distributors
as
(
select A.CONTRACT_ID,A.CONTRACT_ref_num,A.BA_INT_ID,LISTAGG(B.WHOLE_NAME,' | ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.CONTRACT_ID DESC) Distributors
from MN_BA_INT A, MN_BA_INT_WHOLE B, MN_STRUCTURED_DOC C 
where 
A.CONTRACT_ID=C.struct_doc_id 
AND A.BA_INT_ID=B.BA_INT_ID 
--and struct_doc_id=13603
--and struct_doc_id=13685
group by A.CONTRACT_ID,A.CONTRACT_ref_num,A.BA_INT_ID
),

prev_cont_Id
as
(
select a.struct_doc_id,b.alternate_id PREV_CONT_ID from
(
select a.STRUCT_DOC_id, a.amendment_number, max(a.ver_num) max_ver from mn_structured_contract_ver a group by a.STRUCT_DOC_id,a.amendment_number
) a,
(
select a.STRUCT_DOC_id, a.alternate_id, a.amendment_number,a.ver_num from mn_structured_contract_ver a
) b,
max_amend c
-- section
WHERE
a.STRUCT_DOC_id=b.STRUCT_DOC_id and a.max_ver=b.ver_num and a.amendment_number=c.max_amend-1 and c.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
),


Contract_Orig
as 
(
select a.STRUCT_DOC_ID, a.start_date, a.end_date from MN_STRUCTURED_doc_ver a,
(
select STRUCT_DOC_ID, MIN(VER_NUM) VER_NUM from MN_STRUCTURED_CONTRACT_VER
WHERE AMENDMENT_NUMBER=0 AND CTRT_DOC_STATUS='Off.IMPL'
GROUP BY STRUCT_DOC_ID
) b
where a.STRUCT_DOC_ID=b.STRUCT_DOC_ID
and a.VER_NUM=b.VER_NUM
order by struct_doc_id
),

PriceP
as
(
select calc_obj_id,max(cf_prc_strategy_report_id) cf_prc_strategy_report_id from MN_CF_PRC_STRATEGY_REPORT
group by calc_obj_id
),

Component
as
(
select calc_obj_id,max(cf_prc_component_report_id) cf_prc_component_report_id from MN_CF_PRC_COMPONENT_REPORT
 where  type like '%Basis%'
group by calc_obj_id
),

GetAllSubTypes
as
(
select distinct a.STRUCT_DOC_id,
l.strategy_id,
d.display_name PP_Sub_Type,
l.min_value
FROM
mn_structured_contract a,MN_DYN_ENUM_CONST d,max_amend e,
MN_CF_PRC_COMPONENT_REPORT L, Component M, MN_PRICE_MASTER_LI b
WHERE 
e.max_amend=b.amendment_number
and m.cf_prc_component_report_id=l.cf_prc_component_report_id
and l.strategy_id=b.CF_STRATEGY_ID
and b.OVERRIDE_PRICE_RANK=d.code
and a.STRUCT_DOC_id=b.STRUCT_DOC_id
and m.cf_prc_component_report_id=l.cf_prc_component_report_id
and a.STRUCT_DOC_id=e.STRUCT_DOC_id
and d.ns_id in ('734')

-- WHEN THIS CONDITION BELOW IS REMOVED THE SQL FAILS
--and a.struct_doc_id=13685



),

ListSubs
as
(
SELECT STRUCT_DOC_id Contract_ID,LISTAGG(PP_Sub_Type, ' | ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY STRUCT_DOC_id DESC) Contract
FROM GetAllSubTypes
group by STRUCT_DOC_id
),

GetAggCommitt
as
(
select STRUCT_DOC_id, sum(min_value) All_Value from GetAllSubTypes
group by STRUCT_DOC_id
),

GetIndivCommitt
as
(
select STRUCT_DOC_id, PP_Sub_Type, min_value from GetAllSubTypes
),

GetPercentCommitt
as
(
select a.STRUCT_DOC_id, a.PP_Sub_Type, a.min_value Commitment_Val, round(a.min_value/b.all_value,2) Percent_Total from GetIndivCommitt a, GetAggCommitt b
where a.STRUCT_DOC_id=b.STRUCT_DOC_id 
),

Inclusions
as
(
select Contract_ID,
case when Contract='Yes' then 'No SubType' else Contract end PP_SUBTYPES,
case when upper(Contract) like '%WOUND%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Wound_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%OSTOMY%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Ostomy_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%SKIN%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Skin_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%CONTINENCE%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Continence_Included,
case when Contract like '%Mens Health%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Mens_Included,
case when Contract like '%Womens%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Womens_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%Endourology%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end EndoUrology_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%GPO%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end GPO_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%UC%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end UC_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%CHRONIC%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Chronic_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%WSC%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end WSC_Included
from listsubs
)



select distinct 
a.STRUCT_DOC_id,
e.max_amend,
h.member_name Analyst,
h.member_id,
Contract.member_name Customer,
a.ctrt_doc_status Contract_Status,
c.display_name Contract_Type,
a.alternate_id Contract_Number,
prev_cont_id.prev_cont_id Previous_Contract_Number,
Distributors.Distributors,
trunc(dates.start_date) Contract_Start_date,
trunc(Contract_Orig.end_date) Original_End_Date,
trunc(dates.end_date)Contract_End_Date,
mn_Address.Description Customer_Contact_Name,
mn_Address.Line1 Customer_Address,
MN_ADDRESS.CITY Customer_City,
MN_ADDRESS.STATE_PROV Customer_State,
MN_ADDRESS.POSTAL_ZIP Customer_Zip,
Extensions.Num_Extensions,
a.cust_ctrt_id_num,
q.All_Value Total_Commitment,
--Inclusions.PP_SUBTYPES,
Inclusions.Wound_Included,
Inclusions.Ostomy_Included,
Inclusions.Skin_Included,
Inclusions.Continence_Included,
Inclusions.Mens_Included,
Inclusions.Womens_Included,
Inclusions.EndoUrology_Included,
Inclusions.GPO_Included,
Inclusions.UC_Included,
Inclusions.Chronic_Included,
Inclusions.WSC_Included,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Wound%') else '0' end Wound_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Ostomy%') else '0' end Ostomy_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Skin%') else '0' end Skin_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Continence%') else '0' end Continence_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Mens%') else '0' end Mens_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Womens%') else '0' end Womens_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%EndoUrology%') else '0' end EndoUrology_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%GPO%') else '0' end GPO_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%UC%') else '0' end UC_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Chronic%') else '0' end Chronic_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%WSC%') else '0' end WSC_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Wound%') else 0 end Wound_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Ostomy%') else 0 end Ostomy_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Skin%') else 0 end Skin_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Continence%') else 0 end Continence_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Mens%') else 0 end Mens_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Womens%') else 0 end Womens_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%EndoUrology%') else 0 end EndoUrology_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%GPO%') else 0 end GPO_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%UC%') else 0 end UC_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Chronic%') else 0 end Chronic_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%WSC%') else 0 end WSC_Percentage
FROM
MN_PRICE_MASTER_LI b, MN_DYN_ENUM_CONST c, MN_DYN_ENUM_CONST d, max_amend e, 
MN_CF_PRC_STRATEGY_REPORT f, PriceP g, mn_member h, MN_CF_PRC_COMPONENT_REPORT L, Component M, Inclusions, GetAggCommitt Q,
mn_member contract, mn_structured_doc dates, Contract_Orig, mn_Address, prev_cont_id, Extensions, mn_structured_contract a left join Distributors
on Distributors.CONTRACT_ID=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
WHERE b.OVERRIDE_PRICE_RANK IS NOT NULL 
and c.code=a.ctrt_sub_type
and b.OVERRIDE_PRICE_RANK=d.code
and a.STRUCT_DOC_id=b.STRUCT_DOC_id
and a.STRUCT_DOC_id=dates.STRUCT_DOC_id
and a.STRUCT_DOC_id=q.STRUCT_DOC_id
and m.cf_prc_component_report_id=l.cf_prc_component_report_id
and c.ns_id in ('714')
and d.ns_id in ('734')
and e.max_amend=b.amendment_number
and a.STRUCT_DOC_id=e.STRUCT_DOC_id
and l.strategy_id=b.CF_STRATEGY_ID
and g.calc_obj_id=f.calc_obj_id
and g.cf_prc_strategy_report_id=f.cf_prc_strategy_report_id
and h.member_id=a.member_id_author
and contract.member_id=a.member_id_cust
and f.src_id=l.strategy_id
and mn_Address.member_id=a.member_id_cust
and mn_Address.usage_cde=8
and prev_cont_id.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
and Contract_Orig.STRUCT_DOC_ID=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
and Extensions.STRUCT_DOC_ID=a.STRUCT_DOC_id














--CODE SET 2

with max_amend
as
(
select STRUCT_DOC_id, max(amendment_number) max_amend from MN_STRUCTURED_CONTRACT 
group by STRUCT_DOC_id
),

Extensions
as
(
select struct_doc_id, count(*) - 1 Num_Extensions
from 
(
    select distinct struct_doc_id, end_date from MN_STRUCTURED_doc_ver
)
group by struct_doc_id
),

Distributors
as
(
select A.CONTRACT_ID,A.CONTRACT_ref_num,A.BA_INT_ID,LISTAGG(B.WHOLE_NAME,' | ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.CONTRACT_ID DESC) Distributors
from MN_BA_INT A, MN_BA_INT_WHOLE B, MN_STRUCTURED_DOC C 
where 
A.CONTRACT_ID=C.struct_doc_id 
AND A.BA_INT_ID=B.BA_INT_ID 
--and struct_doc_id=13603
--and struct_doc_id=13685
group by A.CONTRACT_ID,A.CONTRACT_ref_num,A.BA_INT_ID
),

prev_cont_Id
as
(
select a.struct_doc_id,b.alternate_id PREV_CONT_ID from
(
select a.STRUCT_DOC_id, a.amendment_number, max(a.ver_num) max_ver from mn_structured_contract_ver a group by a.STRUCT_DOC_id,a.amendment_number
) a,
(
select a.STRUCT_DOC_id, a.alternate_id, a.amendment_number,a.ver_num from mn_structured_contract_ver a
) b,
max_amend c
WHERE
a.STRUCT_DOC_id=b.STRUCT_DOC_id and a.max_ver=b.ver_num and a.amendment_number=c.max_amend-1 and c.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
),


Contract_Orig
as 
(
select a.STRUCT_DOC_ID, a.start_date, a.end_date from MN_STRUCTURED_doc_ver a,
(
select STRUCT_DOC_ID, MIN(VER_NUM) VER_NUM from MN_STRUCTURED_CONTRACT_VER
WHERE AMENDMENT_NUMBER=0 AND CTRT_DOC_STATUS='Off.IMPL'
GROUP BY STRUCT_DOC_ID
) b
where a.STRUCT_DOC_ID=b.STRUCT_DOC_ID
and a.VER_NUM=b.VER_NUM
order by struct_doc_id
),

PriceP
as
(
select calc_obj_id,max(cf_prc_strategy_report_id) cf_prc_strategy_report_id from MN_CF_PRC_STRATEGY_REPORT
group by calc_obj_id
),

Component
as
(
select calc_obj_id,max(cf_prc_component_report_id) cf_prc_component_report_id from MN_CF_PRC_COMPONENT_REPORT
 where  type like '%Basis%'
group by calc_obj_id
),

GetAllSubTypes
as
(
select distinct a.STRUCT_DOC_id,
l.strategy_id,
d.display_name PP_Sub_Type,
l.min_value
FROM
mn_structured_contract a,MN_DYN_ENUM_CONST d,max_amend e,
MN_CF_PRC_COMPONENT_REPORT L, Component M, MN_PRICE_MASTER_LI b
WHERE 
e.max_amend=b.amendment_number
and m.cf_prc_component_report_id=l.cf_prc_component_report_id
and l.strategy_id=b.CF_STRATEGY_ID
and b.OVERRIDE_PRICE_RANK=d.code
and a.STRUCT_DOC_id=b.STRUCT_DOC_id
and m.cf_prc_component_report_id=l.cf_prc_component_report_id
and a.STRUCT_DOC_id=e.STRUCT_DOC_id
and d.ns_id in ('734')

-- WHEN THIS CONDITION BELOW IS REMOVED THE SQL FAILS
and a.struct_doc_id=13685



),

ListSubs
as
(
SELECT STRUCT_DOC_id Contract_ID,LISTAGG(PP_Sub_Type, ' | ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY STRUCT_DOC_id DESC) Contract
FROM GetAllSubTypes
group by STRUCT_DOC_id
),

GetAggCommitt
as
(
select STRUCT_DOC_id, sum(min_value) All_Value from GetAllSubTypes
group by STRUCT_DOC_id
),

GetIndivCommitt
as
(
select STRUCT_DOC_id, PP_Sub_Type, min_value from GetAllSubTypes
),

GetPercentCommitt
as
(
select a.STRUCT_DOC_id, a.PP_Sub_Type, a.min_value Commitment_Val, round(a.min_value/b.all_value,2) Percent_Total from GetIndivCommitt a, GetAggCommitt b
where a.STRUCT_DOC_id=b.STRUCT_DOC_id 
),

Inclusions
as
(
select Contract_ID,
case when Contract='Yes' then 'No SubType' else Contract end PP_SUBTYPES,
case when upper(Contract) like '%WOUND%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Wound_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%OSTOMY%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Ostomy_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%SKIN%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Skin_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%CONTINENCE%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Continence_Included,
case when Contract like '%Mens Health%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Mens_Included,
case when Contract like '%Womens%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Womens_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%Endourology%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end EndoUrology_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%GPO%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end GPO_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%UC%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end UC_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%CHRONIC%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Chronic_Included,
case when upper(Contract) like '%WSC%' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end WSC_Included
from listsubs
)



select distinct 
a.STRUCT_DOC_id,
e.max_amend,
h.member_name Analyst,
h.member_id,
Contract.member_name Customer,
a.ctrt_doc_status Contract_Status,
c.display_name Contract_Type,
a.alternate_id Contract_Number,
prev_cont_id.prev_cont_id Previous_Contract_Number,
Distributors.Distributors,
trunc(dates.start_date) Contract_Start_date,
trunc(Contract_Orig.end_date) Original_End_Date,
trunc(dates.end_date)Contract_End_Date,
mn_Address.Description Customer_Contact_Name,
mn_Address.Line1 Customer_Address,
MN_ADDRESS.CITY Customer_City,
MN_ADDRESS.STATE_PROV Customer_State,
MN_ADDRESS.POSTAL_ZIP Customer_Zip,
Extensions.Num_Extensions,
a.cust_ctrt_id_num,
q.All_Value Total_Commitment,
--Inclusions.PP_SUBTYPES,
Inclusions.Wound_Included,
Inclusions.Ostomy_Included,
Inclusions.Skin_Included,
Inclusions.Continence_Included,
Inclusions.Mens_Included,
Inclusions.Womens_Included,
Inclusions.EndoUrology_Included,
Inclusions.GPO_Included,
Inclusions.UC_Included,
Inclusions.Chronic_Included,
Inclusions.WSC_Included,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Wound%') else '0' end Wound_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Ostomy%') else '0' end Ostomy_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Skin%') else '0' end Skin_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Continence%') else '0' end Continence_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Mens%') else '0' end Mens_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Womens%') else '0' end Womens_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%EndoUrology%') else '0' end EndoUrology_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%GPO%') else '0' end GPO_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%UC%') else '0' end UC_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Chronic%') else '0' end Chronic_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%WSC%') else '0' end WSC_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Wound%') else 0 end Wound_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Ostomy%') else 0 end Ostomy_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Skin%') else 0 end Skin_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Continence%') else 0 end Continence_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Mens%') else 0 end Mens_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Womens%') else 0 end Womens_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%EndoUrology%') else 0 end EndoUrology_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%GPO%') else 0 end GPO_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%UC%') else 0 end UC_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Chronic%') else 0 end Chronic_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%WSC%') else 0 end WSC_Percentage
FROM
MN_PRICE_MASTER_LI b, MN_DYN_ENUM_CONST c, MN_DYN_ENUM_CONST d, max_amend e, 
MN_CF_PRC_STRATEGY_REPORT f, PriceP g, mn_member h, MN_CF_PRC_COMPONENT_REPORT L, Component M, Inclusions, GetAggCommitt Q,
mn_member contract, mn_structured_doc dates, Contract_Orig, mn_Address, prev_cont_id, Extensions, mn_structured_contract a left join Distributors
on Distributors.CONTRACT_ID=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
WHERE b.OVERRIDE_PRICE_RANK IS NOT NULL 
and c.code=a.ctrt_sub_type
and b.OVERRIDE_PRICE_RANK=d.code
and a.STRUCT_DOC_id=b.STRUCT_DOC_id
and a.STRUCT_DOC_id=dates.STRUCT_DOC_id
and a.STRUCT_DOC_id=q.STRUCT_DOC_id
and m.cf_prc_component_report_id=l.cf_prc_component_report_id
and c.ns_id in ('714')
and d.ns_id in ('734')
and e.max_amend=b.amendment_number
and a.STRUCT_DOC_id=e.STRUCT_DOC_id
and l.strategy_id=b.CF_STRATEGY_ID
and g.calc_obj_id=f.calc_obj_id
and g.cf_prc_strategy_report_id=f.cf_prc_strategy_report_id
and h.member_id=a.member_id_author
and contract.member_id=a.member_id_cust
and f.src_id=l.strategy_id
and mn_Address.member_id=a.member_id_cust
and mn_Address.usage_cde=8
and prev_cont_id.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
and Contract_Orig.STRUCT_DOC_ID=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
and Extensions.STRUCT_DOC_ID=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Nobody here is going to try to read a wall of code.

Comment: WOW thank you so much.  You both are absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

The line you've commented out in code set 1 causes the common tables expression named GetAllSubTypes to return a single row. Without it this common table expression returns multiple rows which, given how it's used later, results in a subquery which is required to return a single row to end up returning more than one row. I haven't done an exhaustive analysis because I don't have access to your database, but it appears that the affected code is in the case statements:

```
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Wound%') else '0' end Wound_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Ostomy%') else '0' end Ostomy_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Skin%') else '0' end Skin_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Continence%') else '0' end Continence_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Mens%') else '0' end Mens_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Womens%') else '0' end Womens_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%EndoUrology%') else '0' end EndoUrology_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%GPO%') else '0' end GPO_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%UC%') else '0' end UC_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Chronic%') else '0' end Chronic_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select min_value from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%WSC%') else '0' end WSC_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Wound%') else 0 end Wound_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Ostomy%') else 0 end Ostomy_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Skin%') else 0 end Skin_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Continence%') else 0 end Continence_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Mens%') else 0 end Mens_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Womens%') else 0 end Womens_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%EndoUrology%') else 0 end EndoUrology_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%GPO%') else 0 end GPO_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%UC%') else 0 end UC_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Chronic%') else 0 end Chronic_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select Percent_Total from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%WSC%') else 0 end WSC_Percentage
```

For example, in the above `GetIndivCommitt` is another common table expression which pulls data from `GetAllSubTypes`. The way it's used in the CASE statement above, the SELECT against `GetIndivCommitt` *must* return a single row or the statement will fail as you've noted. You might be able to patch it up by changing the SELECTs in the CASE statement to use a function which limits the SELECT to returning a single value. In the example below I've added the `LEAST` function to each statement - I don't know if this is actually correct, given your code, but it's intended to serve as an example:

```
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(min_value) from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Wound%') else '0' end Wound_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(min_value) from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Ostomy%') else '0' end Ostomy_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(min_value) from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Skin%') else '0' end Skin_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(min_value) from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Continence%') else '0' end Continence_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(min_value) from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Mens%') else '0' end Mens_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(min_value) from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Womens%') else '0' end Womens_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(min_value) from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%EndoUrology%') else '0' end EndoUrology_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(min_value) from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%GPO%') else '0' end GPO_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(min_value) from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%UC%') else '0' end UC_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(min_value) from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Chronic%') else '0' end Chronic_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(min_value) from GetIndivCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%WSC%') else '0' end WSC_Commit,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(Percent_Total) from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Wound%') else 0 end Wound_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(Percent_Total) from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Ostomy%') else 0 end Ostomy_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(Percent_Total) from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Skin%') else 0 end Skin_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(Percent_Total) from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Continence%') else 0 end Continence_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(Percent_Total) from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Mens%') else 0 end Mens_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(Percent_Total) from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Womens%') else 0 end Womens_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(Percent_Total) from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%EndoUrology%') else 0 end EndoUrology_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(Percent_Total) from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%GPO%') else 0 end GPO_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(Percent_Total) from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%UC%') else 0 end UC_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(Percent_Total) from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Chronic%') else 0 end Chronic_Percentage,
case when Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' then (select LEAST(Percent_Total) from GetPercentCommitt b, mn_structured_contract a 
where b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id and b.PP_Sub_Type like '%WSC%') else 0 end WSC_Percentage
```

The above is intended as an example. It is up to you to determine if this is valid for your usage and to make any needed changes to convert to the code to whatever it is you need it to do.

Best of luck.

Comment: Bob, I used your advice so narrow down my problem and you were right.  It is definitely happening in my Case statement.  Will be starting another thread to get to the bottom of the problem.  I essentially want to use the criterion from my greater where clause within my subquery.  This way I would only get one result from my subquery